# fstrim not remembering trmmed blocks after reboot

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, trim

I use LUKS + LVM full disk encryption (/boot included).

However, after every reboot, the system will trim all by free space, not remembering which blocks were trimmed.

I'm afraid this will wear out my ssd.

```
Aug 07 15:49:18 /: 338.4 GiB (363312041984 bytes) trimmed
[REBOOT]
Aug 07 15:49:45 /: 225.5 MiB (236392448 bytes) trimmed
[NO REBOOT]
Aug 07 16:00:01 /: 1.4 GiB (1476653056 bytes) trimmed
[REBOOT]
Aug 09 08:08:43 /: 338.3 GiB (363260616704 bytes) trimmed
[NO REBOOT]
Aug 09 10:00:02 /: 1.6 GiB (1708560384 bytes) trimmed
[NO REBOOT]
Aug 09 16:00:02 /: 1.2 GiB (1317408768 bytes) trimmed
[NO REBOOT]
Aug 10 09:10:24 /: 4.9 GiB (5261406208 bytes) trimmed
[REBOOT]
Aug 10 15:02:24 /: 338.3 GiB (363209334784 bytes) trimmed
```

Is this the correct behavior?
I would expect, after it reboot, to continue to just trim a few GiB, not all the free space.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR As far as I know, on normal SSDs, running `fstrim` again on the same areas should not generally hurt anything.

`fstrim` goes over the whole filesystem, checks which blocks are not in use by the filesystem and tells the drive.

So the SSD receives a TRIM command such as: "block 123 is not in use by the OS, you may do, whatever you like with it." Most SSD's mark the block as unused and effectively zero the contents. At the next TRIM command for the same block the SSD usually will do this: "Hey, It's already marked as unused. I'm not doing anything and then tell the user that it was successful."

You can use `smartctl --xall /dev/sdX` before and after an `fstrim` to check the wear leveling values (most SSDs have some attributes for wear leveling). They should change only a small amount for the very few blocks that your daemons and such have changed.